# how to add reference to multiple indices in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, splitidx

I am using multiple indices:

```
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=book,title=Index]
\makeindex[name=tools,title = Tools\label{idx:tools}]
\makeindex[name = algorithms,title = Algorithms\label{idx:algorithms}]
```

and I want to add a reference to each of them in the table of contents. I saw somewhere that adding

```
\makeindex[intoc]
```

adds a reference, and indeed it does, but only to the first of these indices. Does anyone know how to add references to all three?

Ofer

Answer (score 4):

Each `\makeindex` call needs an `intoc` option if the relevant index shall appear in the ToC!

Be careful with the `tocbibind` package if this is loaded to, also take care of the correct `toclevel` setting.

There is no global `intoc` option (yet) to specify this for all generated indexes.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=book,intoc,title=Index] 
\makeindex[name=tools,intoc,title = Tools\label{idx:tools}] 
\makeindex[name = algorithms,intoc,title = Algorithms\label{idx:algorithms}]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\blindtext
\index[book]{foo}

\index[tools]{foobar}
\index[algorithms]{foobarfoo}

\printindex[book]

\printindex[tools]

\printindex[algorithms]

\end{document}
```